# What is the single word to describe a person who's USED by another person

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Sam and Alex are friends, co-workers or business partners.. Alex is always trying to benefit from Sam about things which are not belonging to their friendship, work nor partnership.

Looking for a single word to describe Sam, a PERSON WHO'S USED by another person.

Note: I had a word which contains something like "shoe" or "shoes" that can be used to describe Sam, but I really can't remember it..

Answer (score 0):

In a literal sense, Alex uses Sam as a pawn; Sam is a pawn.

> https://www.google.com/search?q=Dictionary%3A+pawn
>
> ### pawn
>
> #### /pɔːn/
>
> *noun*
>
> > a chess piece of the smallest size and value, that moves one square forwards along its file if unobstructed (or two on the first move), or one square diagonally forwards when making a capture. Each player begins with eight pawns on the second rank, and can promote a pawn to become any other piece (typically a queen) if it reaches the opponent's end of the board.
>
> - a person used by others for their own purposes.
>   "he was a pawn in the game of power politics"
>   synonyms:  puppet, dupe, hostage, counter, cog; tool, cat's paw, instrument;
>   *informal* stooge
>   "she was a pawn in the battle for the throne"